# ¿Cuál es el origen de "trancazo" como sinónimo de "gripe"?

Tags: etimología, historia, españa, vocabulario-médico

Pues eso. Al menos en España, es bastante habitual decir:

> Vaya un **trancazo** he pillado :(

Para indicar que hemos cogido un resfriado, una gripe, o similar.

Lo cierto es que no esperaba encontrarlo en el diccionario con esa acepción, pero sí, ahí está:

> **[trancazo](http://dle.rae.es/?w=trancazo)**
>
> 2. m. coloq. gripe.

¿Desde cuándo tiene esta palabra dicha acepción? ¿Cuál es el origen? ¿Se entiende fuera de España?

Comment: A esa definición 2 coloquial que aparece en la RAE le falta la región. Por aquí para nada una gripe es un trancazo.

Comment: No me da confianza esta respuesta, pero al menos es muy graciosa: https://www.vissualbook.com/2015/11/13/el-origen-de-tener-un-trancazo/

Comment: En Colombia solo aplica la definición 1 **Golpe que se da con una tranca** y la definición de **A los trancazos=de forma descuidada o desordenada.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues nos vamos a tener que ir un poco más lejos de lo que pensaba. Tenemos esta palabra en el DLE desde... ¡1899! Antes de esa fecha, en 1895 también aparece un sentido figurado de *trancazo* en el diccionario de Zerolo, pero con el significado de "dengue" (que, en el mismo diccionario, se definía como "fiebre epidémica especial que también se llama *trancazo* o *influenza*").

Sobre su origen, un *trancazo* es un golpe, y se usaba tanto en su sentido real como en el figurado:

> *Tú, con esas ilusiones tontas y esa manía de verlo todo color de rosa, me haces un daño horrible, porque viene luego el trancazo de la realidad, y todo se vuelve negro.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Miau", 1888 (España).

Así que es normal que una enfermedad que te deja en la cama como si te hubieran molido a palos se denominara así:

> *Las fiebres sinocales se desarrollan á veces endémica y epidémicamente sin que podamos explicarnos el motivo de esto ni de lo particular de sus manifestaciones, de su marcha y de lo lento de su convalecencia, como sucedió con la enfermedad que los andaluces denominaron dengue ó trancazo, de la que quedaban algunos que la habían padecido en una situacion molesta y de larga duracion con una ineptitud para el ejercicio y aun el menor movimiento y en un estado moral de abatimiento (sin duda este fué el motivo de la denominacion estravagante), que hacía interminables las reposiciones de estados morbosos que ni un momento quizá pusieron en peligro á los calenturientos.*
>
> Ecequiel Martín de Pedro, "Manual de Patología y clínica médicas", 1876 (España).

En este último texto podemos ver que la denominación *trancazo*, tal y como cita el Zerolo, al principio se usaba para el *dengue* y se originó en Andalucía, por el motivo que ya había supuesto (el estado de cansancio físico y de abatimiento en el que se sume el paciente). Nótese, en todo caso, que por entonces el *dengue* era una voz usada para denominar lo mismo que el *trancazo* o la *grippe*. De hecho *dengue* fue un término inventado en Cádiz, "viendo los hijos de aquella tierra que los atacados [por el *trancazo*] *se ponían [dengosos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CBY6rnn)*" ([fuente](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001360618&page=2&search=trancazo%20dengue&lang=es)). Se confirma viendo este texto en el que se usa *trancazo* para describir los síntomas de un resfriado, no del *dengue* tal y como lo conocemos hoy:

> *He tenido estos días una especie de "trancazo" algo molesto -enfermedad del tiempo-, y aunque con la comodidad y regalo de la casa materna se va aliviando, todavía estoy algo flojo e intermitente para todos los quehaceres, y esto mismo ha ido dilatando mi vuelta a ésa.*
>
> Marcelino Menéndez Pelayo, "Carta de 15 de enero de 1902", 1902 (España).

E incluso médicos famosos han usado la palabra en sus libros usando el mismo símil:

> *En la gripe, la raquialgia es menos intensa y se acompaña de dolores en otras regiones (dolor de "paliza", de "trancazo"). Se trata de dolores musculares.*
>
> Gregorio Marañón, "Manual de diagnóstico etiológico", 1943 (España).

En todo caso, no encuentro referencias acerca de por qué los andaluces denominaron *trancazo* a esta dolencia, más allá de porque los ataques eran generalmente repentinos y desprovistos de síntomas premonitorios ([fuente](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003503096&page=9&search=trancazo%20dengue&lang=es)). Vamos, que te golpeaba sin avisar.

Comment: Interesting that in the early days dengue fever was called break-bone fever in English. Whether that has anything to do with being hit by a _tranca_ I have no idea.